# Where is physically the database in a WebSQL app?

Tags: android, html, sqlite, cordova

I've created a simple APP to add some data in a database. While I was testing on Linux Chrome browser, I had no problem accessing to the database itself (path `.config/google-chrome/Default/databases/http_localhost_8383/`) but now I'm testing on a real Android device and I can't find the file that the APP is generating.

Note that I'm using a root browser on a rooted device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, the db should be located at '/data/data/' + this.packageName + '/databases/' + dbName Are you sure it's being created? And to quote brodybits "When the app calls sqlitePlugin.openDatabase(), the plugin will create the database file if it does not exist, or read the database file if it does exist. For each platform, the database file should be in the same path (relative to your app) regardless whether you are running it on an emulator or on a real device."

It sounds like to me that you're using the browser database plugin, instead based on the location of your database.

Chrome save its db's in ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/databases but it's not the same as cordova's sqlite plugin cordova-sqlite-storage.

Comment: Yes, the database has been created: I have add some data, restart and the data is there... The only thing that I have different to what you say in your answer is that I don't call sqlitePlugin.openDatabase() but window.openDatabase(), does it make any difference?

Comment: Of course it does. That's the browser's database not cordova.

Comment: WebSQL is deprecated, btw.

Comment: Ooopppsss... I have edited the question to reflect that this is a WebSQL app. In this case, is it possible to access the file?

Comment: Try Android Device monitor -> File Explorer -> data -> data -> yourpackagename ->app_webview -> should be here, i think

Comment: Yes, it's there

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can be helpful:

```
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
        DB_PATH = xcontext.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";
    } else {
        DB_PATH = xcontext.getFilesDir().getPath() + "data/" +
                xcontext.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
    }
```

or:

```
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
        DB_PATH = xcontext.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";
    } else {
        DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + xcontext.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
    }
```